# Can't search two string objects with whereKey for textDidChange

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchbar

I have an `tableView` in which i'm loading my data from Parse. Now I want to use parse to display search results from the searchBar.text. I've got the firstname and the lastname in which I both want to search in. Problem is that I don't know how to query search 2 objects in a Class and present the filtered matches in the `tableView`. It fully works with one object.

I've tried to do 2 whereKey methods but failed, it wil only present the cell in which both first letters of the objects begin with; example: John Johnsen

Hope I made my problem clear.

**Update 2:**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar! =  UISearchBar()

var timeLineData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.delegate = self

    ....
}

func loadData(name:String){
    timeLineData.removeAllObjects()

    var firstName = PFQuery(className: "Newfamilie")
    firstName.whereKey("voornaam", containsString: name)

    var lastName = PFQuery(className: "Newfamilie")
    lastName.whereKey("achternaam", containsString: name)

    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([firstName, lastName])
    query.orderByAscending("achternaam")
    query.limit = 200
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects{
                let naam:PFObject = object as PFObject
                self.timeLineData.addObject(naam)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.refreshTimeLineControl.endRefreshing()

            println("\(self.timeLineData.count)")
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.loadData("")
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return timeLineData.count
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    loadData(searchText)
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    loadData("")
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell

    let persoon:PFObject = self.timeLineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as PFObject
    let voornaam = persoon.objectForKey("voornaam") as String
    let achternaam = persoon.objectForKey("achternaam") as String

    cell.textLabel.text = "\(voornaam) \(achternaam)"

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're searching with the requirements that *both* the first and the last name *must* contain the string to get a result. You need to combine two `PFQuery`-instances - this will give you results in `voornaam` OR `achternaam`, instead of AND.

```
var firstName = PFQuery(className: "Newfamilie")
firstName.limit = 200
firstName.orderByAscending("achternaam")
firstName.whereKey("voornaam", containsString: name)
var lastName = PFQuery(className: "Newfamilie")
lastName.limit = 200
lastName.orderByAscending("achternaam")
lastName.whereKey("achternaam", containsString: name)

var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([firstName, lastName])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (results: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // Results will be data containing the string "name" in "voornaam" OR "achternaam"
        for object in objects{
            let naam:PFObject = object as PFObject
            self.timeLineData.addObject(naam)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        println("\(self.timeLineData.count)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction. The problem is that it won't show me any data in the cell's. It won't even printLn the `self.timeLindeData.count`. I forgot to mention that I've already tried this method, saw it at the Parse Forum. You think it has something to do with the cellAtIndexPath method? Because if I change your `query.findObjects...` with `lastName.findObjects...` it does work. But then still only for the achternaam search.

Comment: Try to print the `naam`-object and see if it gets the right results at all.

Comment: Tried but I get no result. Seems like it won't even do the `for` loop.

Comment: Hm... It's hard to help without the data, but it seems like there's something wrong with the query or data. Try printing `objects` and see if you get any results at all.

Comment: Seems the `orQueryWithSubqueries` method doesn't work at all. I will update my full code above.